# whats purpose of nested query if the result could be obtained by inner query itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I am beginner level in sql queries. I would like to know the purpose of outer query if the result could be obtained from inner query itself. Like in below case we are deleting set of records from a table which are less than particular timestamp(other matching conditions are matching unique keys but I wonder why we need to check equality for unique keys in same table). This query is written for purge process, we are deleting records from a table which are older than particular timestamp and for extra information we execute this query from java. But my question is to understand the purpose of outer query, if we can achieve result from inner query itself.

Nested query we have:

```
DELETE FROM ORDER_LOG T1 
 WHERE EXISTS (select * 
                 FROM (SELECT VENDOR_NBR, ITEM_NBR, ORDER_ID, PDT_CODE, LOG_TS
                         FROM ORDER_LOG WHERE  LOG_TS < "timestamp" 
                        FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY) AS T2 
                WHERE (T1.LOG_TS = T2.LOG_TS 
                  AND T1.VENDOR_NBR= T2.VENDOR_NBR 
                  AND T1.ORDER_ID=T2.ORDER_ID))
```

Non nested query(that I think of executable and produce same result):

```
DELETE FROM ORDER_LOG 
 WHERE  LOG_TS< "timestamp" 
 FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FETCH FIRST 100000 ROWS ONLY` does not work with the `DELETE` instruction, you need to firstly select only those rows, and then delete them. Your second query will delete all entries that satisfy the condition `LOG_TS< "timestamp"`

Comment: Thanks for your response, from your answer I believe given nested query (where we are selecting first 100000 rows) is for executing FETCH statement and we are deleting selected rows from outer query, so I am good with nested query for my project. In general if I don't specify FETCH in query will delete work simply with where clause like 'DELETE FROM ORDER_LOG WHERE LOG_TS<timestamp, so in that case we don't need nested query like mentioned in question right?